# Ребята помогите с кодом Python 3.х. Немого понять, как передать пустую переменную внутри класса

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы

```
AttributeError: 'PipeLine' object has no attribute 'add'
```

Если в начале передаю пустую переменную то она не меняется в функции `str_lists`

Если создаю переменную в функции то ругается:

```
local variable 'add' referenced before assignment
```

```
class PipeLine():
    """docstring for PipeLine."""

    def __init__(self, item, column, tablename, key):
        # super(PipeLine, self).__init__()
        self.item = item
        self.column = column
        self.tablename = tablename
        self.key = key
        self.listing = []

    def add_list(self):
        result = ['Movavi', 'Mag']
        while True:
            for r in result:
                if self.key in ['премьера (мир)', 'премьера (РФ)']:
                    self.listing.append(r.isoformat())
                else:
                    self.listing.append(r)
            break

    def str_lists(self):
        str_list = ','.join(self.item.get("{}".format(self.key)))
        if self.key in [
                'original_title', 'title', 'info', 'слоган',
                'возраст', 'рейтинг MPAA']:
                self.add = str_list
        if self.key in ['премьера (мир)', 'премьера (РФ)']:
            self.add = correction_date(str_list)
        else:
            while True:
                for strlt in str_list.split(', '):
                    if '%' in strlt:
                        self.add = int(re.sub('%', '', strlt))
                    if self.key == 'rating':
                        self.add = float(strlt)
                    if self.key == 'r_critic':
                        self.add = int(strlt)
                    if self.key == 'жанр':
                        self.add = re.sub(',', '', strlt)
                    if self.key == 'бюджет':
                        self.add = int(
                            ''.join(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), strlt)))
                    if 'сборы' in self.key:
                        self.add = int(
                            ''.join(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), strlt)))
                break
        return self.add

    def insert(self):
        if self.str_lists() not in self.listing:
            print('Name Table: ' + self.tablename + '\n' +
                  ' Name column: ' + self.column + '\n' +
                  ' Name addin info: ' + self.str_lists())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в этой строке:

```
return self.add
```

Это из-за того, что атрибут `add` не был создан. А атрибут будет создан при установке ему значения.

Добавьте в `__init__` или в `str_lists` строку:

```
self.add = None
```